# Querying nested json based on wildcard key

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a PostgresQL table which stores a JSON as jsonb:

```
 Column |  Type   |                         Modifiers                         | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
--------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id     | integer | not null default nextval('history_id_seq'::regclass)      | plain    |              | 
 data   | jsonb   | not null                                                  | extended |              |
```

JSON's structure:

```
{
    "20180201": {
        "foo": [{
            "name": "item1",
            "desc": "an item 1"
        }, {
            "name": "item2",
            "desc": "an item 2"
        }],
        "bar": [{
            "name": "item1",
            "desc": "an item 1"
        }, {
            "name": "item2",
            "desc": "an item 2"
        }]
    }
}
```

Each row will contain such a JSON where timestamp is the key of the dictionary.

I want to write a query which'll fetch all `foo` from the JSON of each row.

I am doing this by first getting all keys (doing this in Python):

```
SELECT (jsonb_object_keys(data)) AS key FROM history;
```

Then iterating over all keys, I run the query (python pseudo-code):

```
for key in keys: 
    query = "SELECT data->'%s'->'foo'FROM history" % key
    fetch_and_print_all_rows()
```

How would I do this is a single query instead of first getting all keys and then iterating and getting the `foo` item. Since the timestamp which is used as key can be anything, would be able to do something like `SELECT data->'%'->'foo' FROM history`

Comment: Essential missing detail: does every row have a `foo` item? If not, what's the expected percentage? It would be needlessly expensive to process *all* rows, if you are only interested in a small percentage.

Comment: Yes, every row will have a `foo` item. If there is nothing for `foo`, it might be an empty array. But the chances of it are low. I.e the item itself won''t be missing.

Comment: Then klin's answer is exactly what you need. (Maybe `->` instead of `->>`.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`jsonb_each():`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

```
select id, key, value->>'foo' as foo
from history
cross join jsonb_each(data)

 id |   key    |                                       foo                                        
----+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | 20180201 | [{"desc": "an item 1", "name": "item1"}, {"desc": "an item 2", "name": "item2"}]
(1 row)
```