# cockroachdb jsonb select query

Tags: jsonb, cockroachdb

I have a simple table in CockroachDB v2.0-beta:

```
CREATE TABLE account ( 
   id UUID NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_v4()::UUID, 
   acct JSON NULL,
   CONSTRAINT "primary" PRIMARY KEY (id ASC),
   INVERTED INDEX account_acct_idx (acct),
   FAMILY "primary" (id, acct) 
)
```

I can run a select query to find specific property under acct->properties like this:

```
select acct->>'id' from account where acct @> '{"properties": {"foo": "bar"}}';
```

Is there a way to select subset of the Json blob such as nested property?  Something like this would be helpful:

```
select acct->>'id', acct->>'properties:description' from account 
    where acct @> '{"properties": {"foo": "bar"}}';
```

Thanks in advance for any hints!

Cheers,
~g

Comment: I don't follow your question. What output are you trying to get, exactly? There's nothing preventing you from doing arbitrary lookups on the JSON blob returned from the contains query.

Answer (score 3):

As Jordan mentioned in the comment above, you can already get nested JSON objects using the operators you've referenced in your question. Using your example, I can access the nested object as follows:

```
> CREATE TABLE account (
   id UUID NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_v4()::UUID,
   acct JSON NULL,
   CONSTRAINT "primary" PRIMARY KEY (id ASC),
   INVERTED INDEX account_acct_idx (acct),
   FAMILY "primary" (id, acct)
);
CREATE TABLE

> INSERT INTO account (acct) VALUES ('{"properties": {"foo": "bar"}}');
INSERT 1

> SELECT * FROM account;
                   id                  |              acct
---------------------------------------+---------------------------------
  6fe08368-7720-4ddd-885e-75437b4e0267 | {"properties": {"foo": "bar"}}
(1 row)

> SELECT acct->>'properties' FROM account WHERE acct @> '{"properties": {"foo": "bar"}}';
     ?column?
------------------
  {"foo": "bar"}
(1 row)
```

Note that `->>` returns a string representation of the nested JSON object. As described in our [JSON docs](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/jsonb.html), the operator `->` can be used to return the object itself. This also allows you to chain the operator if you want to access a deeper nested object. For example:

```
> select acct->'properties'->'foo' from account;
  ?column?
------------
  "bar"
(1 row)
```

Comment: Hi Rebecca, does the SELECT support wildcards for sublevels? e.g., this doesn't currently work: select acct->'%'->'foo' from account;

Comment: Hi @ElleFie, no, CockroachDB currently doesn't support that. Postgres doesn't seem to support it either. But as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48651596/querying-nested-json-based-on-wildcard-key), you can achieve the same goal using the jsonb_each() function, which is supported in both CockroachDB and Postgres.