# Get min and max value from a SQL JSON object to update fields?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-13

I have a table in Postgres 13 that looks something like:

```
Column | Type | 
----------------
id       bigint
ts_begin timestamp with time zone
ts_end   timestamp with time zone
data     jsonb not null '{}'::jsonb
```

Unfortunately the data is an array of key value pairs of with a UUID as the key and a timestamp as the value. E.g.

```
{"20220101234-deadbeef": "2021-11-18T09:09:09-05:00", "2022010234-cafefeed": "2021-11-18T08:08:08-05:00", ... }
```

My task to try and get the min and max values from that JSON object as update the `ts_begin` and `ts_end` values for each row.

Because the keys are not consistent, I think that the `->` or `->>` operators are not going to work for this task. Is that correct?

Is there a way to use `json_each` or `json_each_text` (or some other technique in SQL) to accomplish this task?

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26703476/how-to-perform-update-operations-on-columns-of-type-jsonb-in-postgres-9-4 ?

Comment: Thank you for the response, but if I'm understanding correctly that's about updating a value within a JSON object. I'm trying to set a column value from the aggregated data in the JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have an answer using the `jsonb_each_text` function and then a `cross join` adapted from the answer here: [Querying nested json based on wildcard key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48651596/querying-nested-json-based-on-wildcard-key)

```
update my_table as me
set ts_begin = (select min(cast(value as timestamp with time zone)) as min 
                from my_table me_too 
                cross join jsonb_each_text(data) 
                where me.id = me_too.id),
    ts_end = (select max(cast(value as timestamp with time zone)) as max 
              from my_table me_too 
              cross join jsonb_each_text(data) 
              where me.id = me_too.id);
```

To break it into pieces, the `jsonb_each_text` builds a table with two columns `key` and `value` which can easily be aggregated with the `min` and `max` function. Using a `cross join` with a where clause that limits it to the current row ( `me.id = me_too.id` ) allows the correct values to be set.

EDIT:

I think this can be simplified to just:

```
update my_table
set ts_begin = (select min(cast(value as timestamp with time zone) as min 
                from jsonb_each_text(data)),
    ts_end = (select max(cast(value as timestamp with time zone) as max 
              from jsonb_each_text(data));
```

Comment: You can simplify this even further `set (ts_begin, ts_end) = (select min(...), max(...) from ...)`